# In TortoiseSVN on Windows, is there any utility that allows a user to search for text within the repo?

Tags: tortoisesvn

In TortoiseSVN on Windows, is there any utility that allows a user to search for a text string through the repo? We store a bunch of reporting SQL in SVN and would like to expedite the task of impact analysis on reports when corresponding names change etc. Not sure if all the code is within one repo or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you can use **grep** to search all files in a directory.

Open up a Cygwin terminal, and change into your svn directory.
`cd /cygdrive/c/pathtoSVNrepo`

Then use the following command to search all files in the directory.
`grep -REHni searchString .`
Replace 'searchString' with your text that you would like to search for. Note that this can also be a regular expression.

The command will produce output in the format: **fileName**:**lineNumber**: **lineWithMatchingText**

Example output:
[image: image of example output]

If you're only interseted in which files contain the string, just an 'l' to the options. 

`grep -REHnil searchString .`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenGrok](http://oracle.github.io/opengrok/). You will have to connect it to your svn server, but it works great in our company.